# Unpermitted parameter even though it's in my strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Contracts. In this model, I allow PDF uploads of a file in the name of the field `:contract_pdf` which has the associated fields like pdf_file_name and all the other hooblah rails gives you when you create an attachment for your model. I have a simple form where I collect the pdf file like so:

`<%= form.file_field :contract_pdf, required: true %>`

When I check my rails server, the file gets processed and I can see it in the parameters. E.g. here is an example of one I got:

`"contract"=>{"contract_pdf"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd4c5c5dd88 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/d1/z4545454543/T/RackMultipart24534504-544-9zap3z.pdf>, @original_filename="Consulting Agreement.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"contract[contract_pdf]\"; filename=\"Consulting Agreement.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">`

But when it comes time to persisting the data I get this:

`Unpermitted parameter: :contract_pdf`

My strong parameters include :contract_pdf like so:

```
private
   def contract_params
     params.require(:contract).permit(:client_name,:contract_pdf)
   end
```

I have done this exact thing hundreds of times for other PDF attachments in several other rails apps so I have no clue what's going on and have tried things like `permit( contract_pdf: [])` etc.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: just try like this:- `params.require(:contract).permit!` .

Comment: @Gabbar `permit!` whitelist an entire hash of parameters, which is not safe at all... basically it accepts anything. See more [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: @matiss yep you are right, but here i was just saying that if `permit!` resolves problem ? if it does than we can get some hint of this issue.

Comment: I don't know why is this but sometimes this type of things has resolved after restarting the server

Comment: @fool-dev i swear i restarted my server like 3 times last night to make sure that wasn't it. I wake up, and try this again....and tada it's working. fuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: class caching enabled in development.rb?